# How do I apply scroll bar on div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-frontend

I am trying to show the scrollbar beside the items in div but could not do it.
This is my code.

```
{reciters && reciters.length > 0 ? (
        reciters.map((reciter) => (
          <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
            <div
              onClick={(e) => {
                reciterHandler(reciter);
                setActiveId(reciter.id);
              }}
              className={`d-flex align-items-center py-0 curser ${
                reciter.id === activeId && "active"
              }`}
            >
              <FaUserCircle className="fs-3" />
              <span className="ps-3">{reciter.name}</span> <br />
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div className="text-center">
          <span className="spinner-border"></span>
        </div>
      )}
```

I tried to add **style={{overflowY: "scroll"}}** in the div, but it is showing the scroll bar against each item, I want a singe scroll bar for every item in the div.
Like this:

```
<div style={{ cursor: "pointer", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
            <div
              onClick={(e) => {
                reciterHandler(reciter);
                setActiveId(reciter.id);
              }}
              className={`d-flex align-items-center py-0 curser ${
                reciter.id === activeId && "active"
              }`}
            >
              <FaUserCircle className="fs-3" />
              <span className="ps-3">{reciter.name}</span> <br />
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div className="text-center">
          <span className="spinner-border"></span>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You should add this style to the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to apply the `overflow-y: auto` to the containing div so you would do something like:

```
<div style={{overflowY: auto; height: '200px'}} >
  {reciters.map((reciter) => (
    <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
      <div
        onClick={(e) => {
          reciterHandler(reciter);
          setActiveId(reciter.id);
        }}
        className={`d-flex align-items-center py-0 curser ${
          reciter.id === activeId && "active"
        }`}
      >
        <FaUserCircle className="fs-3" />
        <span className="ps-3">{reciter.name}</span> <br />
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

I've added `height: '200px'` to ensure that the containing div doesnt just grow to accommodate the items that are mapped within it.